# What type is of default web service call synchronous or asynchronous in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, asynchronous, synchronous

i will wonder if i get answer to my question my question is that

'What type is of default web service call behaviour *synchronous* or *asynchronous* in ASP.Net and is there any difference when we call a webservice from WCF application and simple asp.net webforms application?'

i tried searching the internet but did not get relevant links or any useful link

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using ASP.NET webservices, when you create a nethod - methodOne - you get three methods generated for you :

- BeginmethodOnd
- methodOne
- EndmthodOne

or something similar. If you call methodOne it is synchronous. You use the other two methods to handle asynchronous calls. You then explicitly determine what call type you are making.

In WCF I am not sure - I've only really used it once.

James :-)